# Como saber se IP da Lan foi setado de forma manual ou dinamicamente?

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

É possível, **talvez** através de **WMI** ou usando outra técnica, saber se um computador esta com seu **IP de rede local *(LAN)*** setado fisicamente *(manualmente)* ou dinamicamente *(geralmente por DHCP)*? Como?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue resposta *"usando outra técnica"*:

Podemos sempre checar o registro pra saber se o dispositivo está utilizando ou não DHCP:

```
Uses Registry;
```

```pascal
var
  Reg:TRegistry;
begin
  Reg:=TRegistry.Create;
  Reg.RootKey:=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  Reg.OpenKey('SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{GUID da sua placa de rede}', False);
  if Reg.ReadInteger('EnableDHCP') = 0 then
    showmessage('Sem DHCP')
  else
    showmessage('Com DHCP');
  Reg.CloseKey;
  Reg.Free;
end;
```

Assim, você tem o status do dispositivo através do registro.